# What does the Backbone.js extend function do?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I understand it is providing static or "class" properties, but I want to understand how it's doing this, is it creating a new object and putting these static properties on the prototype?

Backbone.View.extend(properties, [classProperties])

Comment: The best thing to do is to actually just look at what it's doing - the backbone development version of the code is filled with helpful comments that explain a lot: http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js

Comment: @kinakuta Plus there's the [annotated source code](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html).

Comment: You can do it even without downloading the source code, using Github instead - starting from [this line](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1474), in particular. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone used and internal helper function called `inherits`. You can see the annotated source code [here](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-176). It sets up the prototype chain to provide class-like functionality.